# showing the current location through gps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm developing an app which should show the current location of device in `google maps` on Android.The Problem is I'm not getting the exact or near location of the device.

I have class for :

```
public class GPSLocatorActivity extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

        locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            0, 
            0, 
            locationListener);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        // enable Street view by default
//        mapView.setStreetView(true);

        // enable to show Satellite view
        mapView.setSatellite(true);

        // enable to show Traffic on map
         mapView.setTraffic(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

//        myLocationOverlay=new MyLocationOverlay(this,mapView);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(16); 
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

                /* Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
                        " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                mapController.animateTo(point);
                mapController.setZoom(16);

                // add marker
                MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
                List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                listOfOverlays.clear();
                listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

                String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mapView.invalidate();
            }
        }

        public String ConvertPointToLocation(GeoPoint point) {   
            String address = "";
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                    getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                    point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                        address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

            return address;
        } 

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    class MapOverlay extends Overlay
    {
        private GeoPoint pointToDraw;

        public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
            pointToDraw = point;
        }

        public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
            return pointToDraw;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            // convert point to pixels
            Point screenPts = new Point();


  mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);

        // add marker
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24, null); // 24 is the height of image        
        return true;
    }
    } 
}
```

I added the permisiions in Mainfest file :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have added permisions and use exact Google Api key for maps.

Comment: Are you using Android map apiv2..

Comment: I am using "Google Maps Android v1 API Key" for this

Comment: what you are actually getting..

Comment: In results I am getting a map which always launch with "Tulsa" place.Its not showing my current location.

Comment: its not receive the actual latitude and longitude..right..

Comment: Yes...:( :( .......I want to show device current location. but its not working....:) :( :( help me plz

Comment: Can u Help me @Janmejoy    .....???

Comment: k..check the below links that i have added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try like this..

using this you can get the latitude and longitude for the current location.then pass the value to get the map.

```
   public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

{

@Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

{

loc.getLatitude();

loc.getLongitude();

String Text = “My current location is: “ +

“Latitud = “ + loc.getLatitude() +

“Longitud = “ + loc.getLongitude();

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

Text,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

“Gps Disabled”,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

}

@Override

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

“Gps Enabled”,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

{

}

}

}
```

example links;;

[link1](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-with-gps-and-locationmanager-in-android/)

[link2](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/11/mapview-to-center-on-current-location.html)

[link3](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/04/android-gps-using-how-to-get-current-location-example)

[link4](http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/geting-current-location-in-android-using-gps/)

Comment: I try Both examples...But In my case I want user current Location Through Gps or network.That is when I launch maps....Maps should show user current location...I have tried many tutorials but I am unable to get User current location. Plz Plz Plz help me.....

Comment: here i have edited for you check ..hope it will help you..otherwise send you full code to me using dropbox..i will try..

Comment: Thanks a lot @janmejoy.......really really thanks.....I am now unable to find my location just bcz of you.Thanks a lot Once again...:)))))